# drawing regular solids

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need the LaTex code of the following figure[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You are not really asking anything.

Comment: There is no question, but a statement, which could easily be reformulated as question. I don't think that this is the point here ...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in
     {2112/{( 2  , 0.5)}/{(2,1,1,2)}/right,
      1122/{( 0.5, 2  )}/{(1,1,2,2)}/above,
      1212/{(-1  , 1  )}/{(1,2,1,2)}/left,
      1221/{(-2  ,-0.5)}/{(1,2,2,1)}/left,
      2121/{( 1  ,-1  )}/{(2,1,2,1)}/right,
      2211/{(-0.5,-2  )}/{(2,2,1,1)}/below
     }
     \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
   \draw (1122) -- (1212) -- (1221) -- (2211) -- (2121) -- (2112) -- (1122);
   \draw (1221) -- (2121) -- (1122) -- (1221);
   \draw[dotted] (1212) -- (2211) -- (2112) -- (1212); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```